# Server bans all visitors ip after certain amount of time

Tags: php, wordpress

I have bought a wordpress theme, customized and installed it on http://www.viorelilisoi.ro/ . The thing is that the server keeps banning any of the visitors IP after a certain amount of time spent on the website (usually about 10-20 minutes). http://www.aboveideas.ro/ is hosted on the same hosting server and it seems that this one has no problems. I have contacted the hosting company and they seem to find no problem on their side. My guess is that there is some kind of error or something on the wordpress instance/theme files that makes the server treat any visit as an attack attempt. I tried using the wp error fix plugin, but it didn't reveal any errors. Did any of you guys encountered any similar issues or have any ideas what could possible cause this? Thank you!

SOLVED:

The problem was a script named 'jquery.cookies.js' . It seems it's somehow a common problem. The solution to this is to rename the script to 'jquerycookies.js' and of course update all the links to it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have the same problem when using another theme? Without more information, it's impossible to say what might be wrong here.

Comment: It's not a PHP or Wordpress problem, it's a server side problem. Try to go to Server Fault section.

Comment: I'm not a wordpress person but I assume the IP's are in a database? If so, search the database column name in the theme files and you might narrow it down. Also, instead of a link to your website (cheap advertising?) provide a link to the theme site.

Comment: @EdCottrell I will try to change the theme and see if it makes any difference. Thanks

Comment: @Alex That was my first thought as well, but the guys from the hosting company keep insisting that there's nothing wrong with the server.

Comment: @user2904910 The guys from your hosting company will never tell you that it's their fault.

Comment: @Onimusha The blocked IP's are on the server block list. Once the ip is banned, none of the files on the server can be accessed. The thing is that after some time the server becomes accessible again. PS: I thought the actual link might help the people figure the problem better. No advertising intended whatsoever, the blog is written in Romanian, and the aboveideas link is not even a completed site, it's more like a sandbox.

Comment: @Alex If it were a server side problem, I think it would also affect the aboveideas website, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: In addition to @EdCottrell's comment, check the plugins as well. The theme or a plugin might be hitting the server with ajax requests without the visitor / you noticing.

Comment: @jeroen I have already tried that. All the plugins are disabled. I guess disabling them is enough, or should I remove them completely? Do they have any activity if they are disabled? I incline to think that the theme is actually the problem, or maybe some changes I made on it, although I didn't change any of the themes core functionality, just some design changes. If this is the case, is there any way to determine which part of the code is the issue?

Comment: Check the "Console" tab in Firebug / the developers tools of the browser (the "Net" or "Network" tab would do it too) and check for ajax requests. You might need to do some digging to see where a request originates, but at least you will know where to look.

Comment: /jquery.cookie.js/?ver=3.8.1
 
406 Not Acceptable
 
viorelilisoi.ro
 
12.7 KB
 
91.212.74.152:80  This one is displayed in red. If I'm not mistaking, I think there was another guy that had the same problem and it was caused by the same jquery.cookie script. Could this be my issue as well?

Comment: It seems that the jquery.cookies.js script was indeed the problem. The solution to this was to rename it to jquerycookies.js . Thank you all for your help!